# get specific lags from plot_acf that are over the confidence interval

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

How do I get from this plot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

dta = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data
dta.index = pd.Index(sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('1700', '2008'))
del dta["YEAR"]
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(dta.values.squeeze(), lags=40)
plt.show()
```

the specific lags that are over/under the confidence interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`acf`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html) rather than the plot interface to get the numerical values.  The key step is to center the confidence interval by subtracting the ACF from the confidence interval so that it is centered at 0.  The CI that is returned from `acf` is centered around the estimated ACF value.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf

dta = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data
dta.index = pd.Index(sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('1700', '2008'))
nlags = 40
alpha = 0.05
fft=True
adjusted = False
missing = "none"
bartlett_confint = True
x = dta.SUNACTIVITY
a, ci = acf(x, nlags=40, alpha=0.05)
# Key step
centered_ci = ci - a[:,None]
outside = np.abs(a) >= centered_ci[:,1]
inside = ~outside

print(outside)
```

which shows

```py
[ True  True  True False  True  True  True False False  True  True  True
  True False False  True  True  True False False  True  True  True False
 False False  True  True False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False]
```

Comment: First of all: the code is not working for me. Second: Why is CI equal to 40/2 ? The CI gets bigger the bigger the lag is, or?

Comment: Fixed the small bug and clarified that you need to recenter the confidence interval to get the values produced by `plot_acf`.  CI is not 40/2 -- I meant that it is a 40 by 2 array (really nlags by 2 if nlags differs).